# e4-Javafx: How to apply current theme to login dialog

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, e4, efxclipse

My `e4 javafx` application displays login dialog before diplaying main window.

LifeCycleManager class

```
@PostContextCreate
void postContextCreate(Application app, IEclipseContext econtext){  

    //display login dialog extends org.eclipse.fx.ui.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog
    LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog(null, "Login", "Login title", "Message", "");
    int response = dialog.open();             

    if (response != Dialog.OK_BUTTON) {
         System.exit(0);
    }
    ....
}
```

Dialog has default javafx styling (modena).

How do i get current theme and apply to this dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to get stylesheets from current theme

```
import org.eclipse.fx.ui.services.theme.ThemeManager;

@Inject
ThemeManager themeManager;

ObservableList<URL> stylesheets =  themeManager.getCurrentTheme().getStylesheetURL();
```

Next is to create dummy stage and add stylesheets to it;

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox());
Stage stage = new Stage;
stage.setScene(scene);
for (URL url : stylesheets) 
{
    stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(url.toExternalForm());
}
```

Then set stage as parent window (first parameter) to dialog

```
LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog(stage, "Login", "Login title",
                  "Message", "");
```

Dialog will copy stylesheets from parent stage and will add them to its own stage.

It works. But i doubt it is a "proper" way. There must be other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default styleset for an component by calling:

```
getStylesheets().add(new File("conf/application.css").toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

Did you try this?

Comment: In my case i dont want to add stylesheet from specific file. I need to get stylesheets from current theme (can be many of them (themes)) and add them (stylesheets) to dialog stage.